# Alguem pode me explicar o que é um laço for generico em Lua?

Tags: loop, lua, for, genéricos

Eu já sei os laços `while`,`repeat` e `for`,mas quando eu estava vendo os tipos de laços,na seção eu encontrei o tal do "Laço `for` genérico" . O texto estava em inglês.

Comment: Você conhece outra linguagem? Sabe como é um `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

O manual da versão 5.2 tem uma versão em português, [cuja parte relevante cito abaixo](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#3.3.5):

> O comando **for** genérico funciona usando funções, chamadas de *iteradores*. A cada iteração, a função iteradora é chamada para produzir um novo valor, parando quando esse novo valor é **nil**. O laço **for** genérico tem a seguinte sintaxe:
>
> > comando ::= **for** listanomes **in** listaexps **do** bloco **end**
> >
> > listanomes ::= Nome {**‘,’** Nome}
>
> Um comando **for** como
>
> ```
> for var1, ..., varn in listaexps do bloco end
> ```
>
> é equivalente ao código:
>
> ```
> do
>   local f, s, var = listaexps
>   while true do
>     local var1, ..., varn = f(s, var)
>     if var1 == nil then break end
>     var = var1
>     bloco
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Note o seguinte:
>
> - *listaexps* é avaliada somente uma vez. Seus resultados são uma função *iteradora*, um *estado*, e um valor inicial para a primeira *variável iteradora*.
> - *f*, *s*, e *var* são variáveis invisíveis. Os nomes estão aqui para fins didáticos somente.
> - Você pode usar **break** para sair de um laço **for**.
>     As variáveis de laço *vari* são locais ao laço; você não pode usar o valor delas após o **for** terminar. Se você precisa desses valores, então atribua-os a outras variáveis antes de interromper ou sair do laço.

Então, comentando:

A expressão entre o **in** e o **do** no **for** genérico é uma tripla ordenada; o primeiro elemento é uma função, o segundo é um valor auxiliar, e o terceiro é o índice da iteração.

Na hora de iterar, a função que é o primeiro elemento da tripla vai ser chamada com os outros dois elementos como parâmetros. O segundo elemento é constante durante todo o laço, e *frequentemente* é a coleção que está sendo iterada. O terceiro é o elemento ou índice atual, e vai ser usado pela função para decidir qual é o próximo elemento a retornar.

Por exemplo, vamos examinar um iterador como `pairs(table)`: Se você executar na [*REPL* de demonstração da lua.org](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo):

```
> print(pairs(io))
```

você vai receber de volta algo como o seguinte:

```
function: 0x41b980  table: 0x22d2ca0    nil
```

Ou seja, uma função, uma tabela, e um `nil`. Fazendo:

```
> local f, t, n = pairs(io)
> print((f == next), (t == io), n)
true    true    nil
```

você descobre que a função que a `pairs()` retornou é a `next()` e o objeto é a própria tabela `io` que ela recebeu como parâmetro. Dizendo:

```
> next(io, nil)
write   function: 0x41de30
> next(io, 'write')
nil
```

você percorre os elementos da tabela `io` (que só contém um item naquele ambiente, chamado `write`). Essa execução da `next()` é como rodar o laço "na mão"; o que o **for** faz é simplesmente passar os resultados da `next` para o corpo do laço na ordem em que os recebe.